# Which Driver Should we use for creating page object model in appium

Tags: appium

```
public class logintoindia {

     private AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;

    // private AndroidDriver driver;
   /* private AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;*/

    public logintoindia(AndroidDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
    }
```

I am confussing which driver should i used to initialize page classes for run app by using appium

Answer (score 1):

To use page object model, i suggest you to define AppiumDriver or AndroidDriver as **public static**.

```
public static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;
//initialize DesiredCapabilities and AppiumDriver
```

Then you'll be able to use it in any other class you like. Don't create AppiumDriver or AndroidDriver inside page object model.

Page object should be define like following

```
public class Login {
   public logintoindia(AndroidDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
   }

  @AndroidFindBy(accessibility = "accessibility id")
  MobileElement btn;

  public void clickBtn(){
     btn.click();
  }
}
```

Then from another class

```
public void Test1(){
   Login login= new Login(driver);
   //import driver from the class where you initialize it
   login.clickBtn();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/docs/The-starting-of-an-Android-app.md#possible-cases

> You can use io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver and io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver as well. The main difference is that AndroidDriverimplements all API that describes interaction with Android native/hybrid app. AppiumDriverallows to use Android-specific API eventually.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android you can go for an android driver, for ios use IOSdriver, if you want to go for an appium driver you can use it for both